# SourceTree: Keeps asking for a password to bitbucket.org

Tags: sourcetree

Can't connect to bitbucket.org from SourceTree. Keeps asking for password. Worked fine yesterday with the same project. Works from git command line

Comment: Do you sure you entered the right password?

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue with the newest version 1.6.24 downgrade to 1.6.23 to fix this

here is a link: http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/SourceTreeSetup_1.6.23.exe

link to thread detailing issues:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/164023/password-not-working-on-sourcetree

Comment: will all project bookmarks be kept if i uninstall the new version and install the old one?

Comment: I believe you keep your configs

Comment: Can confirm, just downgraded to 1.6.23 and it's now authenticating correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar thing after an update; I tried re-adding my bitbucket credentials, changing the protocols, etc. with no luck, until...

1. I opened my keychain and searched for bitbucket under the Passwords category.
2. I found that I had multiple Access Keys for my user, so I closed my repository, deleted all the keys of "application password" Kind, opened the SourceTree preferences > Accounts > removed my account and re-added it (login as usual - I used Basic with HTTPS).
3. Keychain asks for permission to save the password, which I said yes and now I only see one key of the kind "application password".

I opened my repository from the repo browser and hey presto, no more password popups!

This bugged me for a whole week! If this helped you, you can do a little dance with me now :)

Comment: Simply removing all the "application password" types fixed this for me.